# What can I do for an Acer garnet's leaves looking dull and dry

Tags: diagnosis, leaves, tree-care, maple

Hi I'm a bit worried about my Acer garnet. I bought it in March and it was planted in a new garden along with another *Acer palmatum*. The Covid virus stopped all work on the new garden so although it was watered little else was done . Now the weather is hot I'm concerned that it's not happy. It's in the sun until about 4 pm when the shade takes over. We have irrigation for the grass that comes on twice a day. The leaves have become so dull and dry. There has been a little wind but the trees are in a sheltered area between a house and a wall. I've read that the roots have to be kept cool but there is grass around the stem of the trees, is it suitable to put some gravel around to keep the roots cooler. I really don't want to move the tree.  It's not had any fertile or anything else apart from some treatment for aphids. Please help I don't want to lose it.

---

Thank you will do now I'm thinking I won't lose this tree although at the moment she still looks forlorn. The new shoots are very encouraging.

Comment: A photo would be helpful, but how much water has it been given over, say, a week? Or is it only watered when the irrigation for the grass comes on?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Before I posted my question the trees were given occasional watering of about 10 litres. Since the irrigation has been in I have given them a thorough watering at the roots. Now I have just looked at Garnet and although the leaves still look dry and have burnt tips there are some new shoots that are emerging so it looks hopeful. Have taken some photos but I don't know how to post them.

Answer (score 1):

If you're seeing new shoots after deep  watering, that was the problem, insufficient  water. When you plant anything new in spring, it will need regular and sufficient supplies of water right through the growing season, and if what you've planted  is a tree or shrub, something with a woody framework, it is even more important. It takes a year to 18 months for a woody based plant to put down a good root system which will let it seek its own water supplies, so while it's doing that, it needs a bit of help with water, particularly during warm, dry periods. Continue to soak the Acers every 6-7 days, watering deeply each time, rather than watering more often with less water; do this up till fall/autumn, unless the weather turns very, very wet for a while.